# Any way to lighten the background of a JPG using Preview?

Tags: preview, graphics, image-editing

I'm on Mac OS Big Sur.  Someone has sent me a picture of a printed page they took with their phone (JPG format) and when I open it in preview the background appears a little dark

[image]

Anything I can do in Preview to lighten the background?  Originally the photo was of a black and white page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools → Adjust Colour. Drag the right slider to the left and the middle slider to the right.

[image]